# In Jmeter how I generate hundreds of xml payload files and use them for the test

Tags: jmeter

Here is what I am trying to do using Jmeter

Firstly,I would like create hundreds of xml payload files with  different values and save them in to a folder at some location-How can I achieve that?

Secondly,I would like to use and run the test the generated xml payload files from the folder of above-How can I achieve that?

Much appreciated the thoughts!

Thanks, Raj

Comment: For creating the files you will need either a text editor with a scripting feature or a word processor with a mail merge feature.  What OS and software do you have available?

Answer (score 2):

1. For creating XML you can use a suitable JSR223 Test Element, i.e. [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and generate XML files using [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_creating_xml) code like:

   ```
   import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
   import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils
   import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils

   1.upto(2, {
       def writer = new StringWriter()
       def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
       xml.records() {
           foo(name: RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(5), make: RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(7), year: RandomUtils.nextInt(1000, 9999)) {
               country(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10))
               record(type: RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(15), RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(10))
           }
       }
       new File("test" + "$it" + ".xml") << writer
   })
   ```

   it will create files like `test1.xml` and `test2.xml` with random content in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
2. The easiest way of using the generated files is [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter) element, it reads files from the specified folder into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which will hold the path to the specified file. The file in its turn can be "read" using [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function

Comment: #2  I get it . But  for #1 Is it possible to generate the xml payload files files and save them into a folder via csv config? .I know  how to use csv and paremetize the values , but how can i generate the paramerized xml payload and save them into a folder